# relative paths to image file in wordpress (3.3.1) custom fields?

Tags: wordpress

I've set-up a basic template that contains custom fields meta:

```
 <?php
 /*

 Template Name: Store Page

 */ 


 get_header(); the_post();?>

    <div id="primary">
        <div id="content" role="main">
                        <div class="main-image">

             <img src='<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'main-image',true);?>'/>

                        </div>


        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

  <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I have a custom field that displays an image but i can't seem to work out how to display the image in the custom value field without using the full path to the image file ? see below:

[image]

It displays fine with the full path.

If i try and use images/individual01.jpg in custom field value the image does not appear. is it possible to enter a relative path to the file ?

Any ideas ? Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative paths are relative to the current URL/route. So `images/individual01.jpg` is relative to whatever page you're on. Assuming you're using pretty URLs, `http://127.0.0.1/my-page` would link to that image as `http://127.0.0.1/my-page/images/individual01.jpg`. Of course, we know that doesn't exist, which is why the image doesn't work.

Relative URLs are ok in css, but not in the template of a routed web application. There's heaps of plugins that will do this for you anyway, might be better off using one of them instead: http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/