# Rewrite img src url's on localhost, Wordpress and Custom Fields

Tags: php, html, wordpress, url, image

I am trying to load images through custom fields, rather than using the featured image.

My custom fields are as follows

```
name:  image-small
value: /images/thumbs/small/example.jpg
```

PHP

```
<img src='<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image-small', true); ?>'>
```

yet instead of writing the img src as

```
http://localhost/project.co.uk/images/thumbs/small/example.jpg
```

it displays

```
http://localhost/images/thumbs/small/example.jpg
```

is there a way to either write the htaccess so that it re-routes the url or, do I have to hardcode it into the HTML until I go live, then replace the code with whats above? Or is there a much easier way to do it?

I have found

- [relative paths to image file in wordpress (3.3.1) custom fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601637/relative-paths-to-image-file-in-wordpress-3-3-1-custom-fields)

but it didn't help me resolve it.

Comment: Perhaps: `<img src='<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . 'image-small', true); ?>'>`?

Comment: i will try that. thanks Dave/David :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the URL in that field begins with a "/", which means "go back to the root of the domain". Since as far as your browser is concerned the domain is "localhost", you get the "http://localhost/images/..." resolution.

Note that it's your browser doing this interpretation, not the PHP code.

What you need to do is echo at the beginning of the src="" attribute the base that you want to put on the URL, so that you're outputting the full URL from "http://" onwards. Looking at your example, this will probably be [home_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url) or [site_url()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/site_url)

That is, your code will become something like: `<img src='<?php echo home_url() . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image-small', true); ?>'>`